# How to do value weighted based on maximum-minimum data value in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to do data weighting by using numbers 1-4 to replace the value of the data based on the order of magnitude of the values ​​(minimum to maximum) from datagridview and I'm using visual basic to code my program.

This is the table for the initial data:

| Method | Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| FCFS | 146 |
| SPT | 143 |
| LPT | 253.25 |
| EDD | 192.25 |

I want to weighting the value of column1 based on the maximum-minimum value and then display it in column "Result", with this terms and conditions:

- "1" is for the minimum number in column1
- "2" is for the 2nd minimum number in column1
- "3" is for 3rd minimum number in column1
- and "4" is for maximum number in column1

The final result that i want to show is like the table below:

| Method | Column1 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FCFS | 146 | 2 |
| SPT | 143 | 1 |
| LPT | 253.25 | 4 |
| EDD | 192.25 | 3 |

can you help me to write the syntax to get the "result"? I'm sorry for my poor english.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You will find very few people with write the code for you.  You at least should show us an attempt.  Start with a pen an paper maybe and map out the logic you need.  Maybe something like order the records by values, then iterate the ordered list to apply weightings

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to post an image but I can't bcs i should have at least 10 reputation to post an image :(

Comment: Posting an image has nothing to do with it.  Edit your question and copy and paste what you've got so far with a clear explanation of how it's not meeting expectations

Comment: I've edit my question, is it clear enough to understand?

Comment: Oh my god I'm sorry, i put the wrong number in the table..

Comment: When people ask questions like this, it seems that they think that code materialises out of thin air. Code is simply an implementation of logic. The logic is nothing to do with programming specifically so it requires no programming experience; just an effort to think logically. If you had to do this manually, i.e. with pen and paper, what steps would you perform? Not surprisingly, you need to perform the same steps in code. YOU need to come up with the logic and then YOU need to try to implement that logic in code. If you get stuck, explain the logic and show us the code so far.

Comment: For the record, you're not talking about weighting but rather ranking. You're basically ordering the rows by the values in a particular column. That should give you a clue, i.e. you need to sort the data and then the index in the sorted list will give you the rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the order of datagridview rows, you can sort datagridview directly.

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns("Column1"), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Otherwise, you can refer to the following example.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Method")
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1")
    dt.Rows.Add("FCFS", 146)
    dt.Rows.Add("SPT", 143)
    dt.Rows.Add("LPT", 253.25)
    dt.Rows.Add("EDD", 192.25)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim col As DataGridViewColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    col.Name = "Result"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)

    Dim weighting As Integer = 1
    Dim dic As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    Dim arr As String() = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Select(Function(x) x.Cells("Column1").Value.ToString).ToArray()
    Array.Sort(arr)
    For Each key In arr
        dic.Add(key, weighting)
        weighting += 1
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim col1Cell = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Column1").Value.ToString
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Result").Value = dic(col1Cell)
    Next
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you so much. You are genius